# Simple chain of promisified function wrapper?

Tags: promise, bluebird

For example A is an existing object with API following node.js convention:

```
function A() {
}

A.prototype.op = function (cb) {
    cb(undefined, 'success');
};

A.prototype.op2 = function (cb) {
    cb(undefined, 'success 2');
};

A.prototype.log = function(r) {
    console.log(r);
};
```

When I do `Promise.promisifyAll(A.prototype)` I will get generated `*Async()` functions.
I would like to have a readable chain like this:

```
Promise.bind(a)
.then(a.opAsync)
.then(a.op2Async)
.then(a.log);
```

I know that this doesn't work because we need additional function wrapper returning promise:

```
Promise.bind(a).then(function() {
    return this.opAsync();
}).then(function(){
    return this.op2Async();
}).then(function(r) {
    this.log(r);
});
```

Do I have to write wrapper for every promisified function? Or there is a better way to design this API?

Comment: doing `Promise.bind(a).then(a.opAsync).then(a.op2Async).then(a.log);` should work just fine. Why would you expect it not to?

Comment: It doesn't work. Look at the example `ajaxGetAsync` in [link](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#thenfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise) - it is also wrapped in annonymous function returning promise.

Comment: That's only because it takes an additional parameter, and you could do it `with `Function#bind`. It's written this way to look less confusing to newcomers.

Comment: Ok, I missed additional parameter in example. Look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sA99/13/) for my problem. I think I know why this doesn't work, but I can't explain it :)
Fulfill handler of `then` should be normal function returning Promise, but I am passing auto generated promisified functions with different API.

Comment: Oh, that's cool, it's binding the `this` value for the promise but the lookup for the non-promisified function from the promisified one uses context differently. My bad, please file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a dummy parameter to original function resolved the problem.

```
A.prototype.op2 = function (x, cb) {
    cb(undefined, 'success 2');
};
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4sA99/16/)

[Issue with details](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/327)